# The template validation failed:

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

When save flow it throws error - The template validation failed: 'The 'recurrence' property of template trigger 'When_an_item_is_created' at line '1' and column '987' is not defined or not valid.'.

This error is coming for new and all existing flows. Tried all options - incognito window, sign out/sign in, different browsers, close all session and opens after some time but no use

```
{
    "inputs": {
        "host": {
            "connection": {
                "name": "@parameters('$connections')['shared_sharepointonline']['connectionId']"
            }
        },
        "method": "get",
        "path": "/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('https://****.sharepoint.com/sites/****'))}/tables/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('id'))}/onnewitems",
        "authentication": "@parameters('$authentication')"
    },
    "recurrence": {
        "interval": -0.016666666666666666,
        "frequency": "Minute"
    },
    "splitOn": "@triggerBody()?['value']"
}
```

Everytime error is: The template validation failed: 'The 'recurrence' property of template trigger 'When_an_item_is_created' at line '1' and column '987' is not defined or not valid.'.

Answer (score 1):

I've investigated a little bit more and found the issue. Any "Automated Trigger" seems to be bringing a negative recurrence time. Here´s the code for the "When a file is created or modified in a folder" trigger (and any other "When a file/item..." option) in SharePoint triggers:

[When a new file is added to a folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGkzO.png)

The recurrence interval is negative! When using a Recurrence or PowerApps trigger this issue can be avoided. In the Recurrence trigger the recurrence time must be set to a positive value (if you have this issue, just create a new Recurrence trigger to test and you'll see the negative value selected by default. You won't be able to save the flow unless you change it to a positive one).
Since the user cannot adjust this value in Automated triggers, the platform cannot be used. Previously saved Flows continue to work without issues, but no new flows can be added, and the old ones cannot be modified either.
This looks like a very serious BUG! Hopefully Microsoft will address it immediately.

Comment: You are correct, the trigger recurrence is -ve here. I validated it in different tenants, there value is +ve. The question is how it had automatically changed.
This looks like a very serious BUG! - it is. We addressed it to Microsoft, hopefully they will resolve it today.